# How do I change the position of the navigation bar in Bing Maps 7?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have a Bing Map and I'm using the navigation bar (the white bar with zoom controls). The bar is on the left side but I want it to be on the right side. How do I position the bar on the right side of the map?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bing Maps but I'd use FireBug to analyze the CSS rules and add a stylesheet to override the rules regarding the navbar position.

Comment: Yeah, this is the right solution I think but I just scripted up a JS solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a Javascript solution. I created a Javascript interval that waits for the map to load and then repositions the navigation bar. I'm sure there is a more elegant CSS solution that I could have used but this worked well enough.

```
    var intervalRepsotionNavBar = setInterval(RepositionNavigationElement, 50);

    function RepositionNavigationElement() {
        var navBar = $('.NavBarFull', mapElem);
        var mdr = $(mapDrawingRegion);
        if (navBar.length > 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalRepsotionNavBar);
            navBar.css('left', mdr.innerWidth() - navBar.innerWidth());
        }
    }
```